# Issues with setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a simple slideshow using jQuery and some javascript, but I'm running into issues using the setInterval functions.

[***JSFiddle of the Project***](http://jsfiddle.net/6hmwbqja/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

slidePos = 1;
autoScrollInterval = setInterval(function () {
    slidePos = SlideRight(slidePos)
}, 7000);
$(".ss-indicator-arrow").css("width", $(".ss-slideshow").width() / $(".ss-slide").length);

$(".ss-right-arrow").click(function () {
    window.clearInterval(autoScrollInterval);
    slidePos = SlideRight(slidePos);
    setTimeout(function () {
        autoScrollInterval = setInterval(function () {
            slidePos = SlideRight(slidePos)
        }, 7000);
    }, 10000);
});

$(".ss-left-arrow").click(function () {
    window.clearInterval($.autoScrollInterval);
    slidePos = SlideLeft(slidePos);
    setTimeout(function () {
        autoScrollInterval = setInterval(function () {
            slidePos = SlideRight(slidePos)
        }, 7000);
    }, 10000);
})
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    $(".ss-indicator-arrow").css("width", $(".ss-slideshow").width() / $(".ss-slide").length);
    Reset();
});

function SlideRight(slidePos) {
    slidePos++;
    if (slidePos <= $(".ss-slide").length) {
        $(".ss-container").css("margin-left", -((slidePos - 1) * $(".ss-slideshow").width()) + "px");
        $(".ss-indicator-arrow").css("left", ($(".ss-indicator-arrow").width() * (slidePos - 1) + "px"));
    }
    else
        Reset();

    return slidePos
}

function SlideLeft(slidePos) {
    slidePos--;
    if (slidePos > 0) {
        $(".ss-container").css("margin-left", -((slidePos - 1) * $(".ss-slideshow").width()) + "px");
        $(".ss-indicator-arrow").css("left", ($(".ss-indicator-arrow").width() * (slidePos - 1) + "px"));
    }
    else {
        slidePos = $(".ss-slide").length;
        $(".ss-container").css("margin-left", -((slidePos - 1) * $(".ss-slideshow").width()) + "px");
        $(".ss-indicator-arrow").css("left", ($(".ss-indicator-arrow").width() * (slidePos - 1) + "px"));
    }

    return slidePos;
}

function Reset() {
    slidePos = 1;
    $(".ss-container").css("margin-left", "0px");
    $(".ss-indicator-arrow").css("left", "0px");
}
```

So far I've tried many different methods, and have somewhat ruined the basic functionality I had before. But for now, the primary issue is that if an arrow is pressed multiple times, after the wait setTimeout period, it will then progress through the same number of slides (ie if the button is pressed 3 times, when the setInterval starts over it will move 3 slides again)

**What is the most effective way I can have an interval that pauses after user input, then resumes again?**

Comment: try not to use setInterval, but the `var runinterval = ...; ...; (function selfrunning() { /* do code here */ if(runinterval) { setTimeout(selfrunning, runinterval); }}());` pattern. Functions the same, but infinitely easier to debug, and doesn't keep running if there's errors in your code anywhere.

Comment: You could try unbind your event after the arrow is clicked and rebind it on the callback when your slide animation finishes.

Comment: +1 to @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans comment, `setTimeout` is way more consistent and easier to test than `setInterval`, plus you avoid issues you never would have thought of (AJAX-delivered content, for example).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I think I understand what you mean, but if you have a demo that would be great. Also how would I go about implementing the pause after user input?

Comment: @Renson sure: http://jsbin.com/xipixolabofi/1/

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have the interval working, but I'm running into the same issue as before, where the show will now skip based on the previous number of slides pressed. It's likely an error due to my `slidePos` variable

Answer (score 0):

> What is the most effective way I can have an interval that pauses
>   after user input, then resumes again?

Look at this example
DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/n8c3pycw/1/

```
var Timer = {
    totalSeconds: 300,

    start: function () {
        var self = this;

        this.interval = setInterval(function () {
            self.totalSeconds -= 1;
            if (self.totalSeconds == 0) {
                Timer.pause();
            }
            $("#timer").text(parseInt(self.totalSeconds, 10));
        }, 1000);
    },
    pause: function () {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        delete this.interval;
    },

    resume: function () {
        if (!this.interval) this.start();
    }
}

Timer.start();
$("#start").click(function(){
    Timer.resume();
});
$("#stop").click(function(){
    Timer.pause();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using either setTimeout or setInterval.

```
example: var autoScrollInterval = runInterval();

function tochangeyourimage (delta) {
  autoRunInterval = runInterval();
};

function runInterval() {
  return setInterval(tochangeyourimage, 7000, 1);
```