# Javascript remembering intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently posted about issues using intervals in a slideshow ([Issues with setInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25452448/issues-with-setinterval)), and was hoping that getting away from setInterval would solve all my problems, but it did not.

I have a problem with the next slide function "remembering" the number of clicks (and even the speed between clicks) and repeating that number every time an interval fires. Usually, after user input, the function should pause for a time, then return to an interval of one slide at a time, but instead will start an interval based on the user clicks.

For example: The user slicks the next slide button four times, the show moves four slides, then takes a pause, after which it will move another four slides (instead of just one).

Below is my javascript (with portions removed based on relevance):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

slidePos = 1;
runInterval = 7000;
setTimeout(AutoScroll, runInterval);

$(".ss-right-arrow").click(function () {
    SlideRight();
    runInterval = false;
    setTimeout(function () {
        runInterval = 7000;
        AutoScroll();
    }, 15000);
});

$(".ss-left-arrow").click(function () {
    SlideLeft();
    runInterval = false;
    setTimeout(function () {
        runInterval = 7000;
        AutoScroll();
    }, 15000);
})
});

function AutoScroll() {
    if (runInterval) {
        SlideRight();
        setTimeout(AutoScroll, runInterval);
    }
}

function SlideRight() {
    slidePos = slidePos + 1;
    if (slidePos <= $(".ss-slide").length) {
        $(".ss-container").css("margin-left", -((slidePos - 1) * $(".ss-slideshow").width()) + "px");
        $(".ss-indicator-arrow").css("left", ($(".ss-indicator-arrow").width() * (slidePos - 1) + "px"));
    }
    else
        Reset();
}

function SlideLeft() {
    slidePos--;
    if (slidePos > 0) {
        $(".ss-container").css("margin-left", -((slidePos - 1) * $(".ss-slideshow").width()) + "px");
        $(".ss-indicator-arrow").css("left", ($(".ss-indicator-arrow").width() * (slidePos - 1) + "px"));
    }
    else {
        slidePos = $(".ss-slide").length;
        $(".ss-container").css("margin-left", -((slidePos - 1) * $(".ss-slideshow").width()) + "px");
        $(".ss-indicator-arrow").css("left", ($(".ss-indicator-arrow").width() * (slidePos - 1) + "px"));
    }
}
```

I have tried multiple methods for intervals (eg i++, ++i, += 1, etc), and have also tried moving the interval to outside of the functions, but neither has yielded results.

So the question is:

**Why is my function "remembering" the user input and how can I stop that?**

Comment: Try to assign an interval to a variable and clear it using ``clearInterval`` method everytime you need it.

Comment: You should usually cancel a previous timeout when setting a new one. `var timeoutId;// Define it first;` Now, everytime you call setTimeout, do the following:   `if (timeoutId) { clearTimeout(timeoutId);}  timeoutid = setTimeout(function(){});` Your `runInterval` is very confusing. Instead of remembering if you should run a timeout, do what I suggested above and I think your problem will go away. It is possible to make what you have work, but as it stands, it looks really messy